# Android Firebase upload file time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Hi I am implementing the storage upload in firebase for images.

What I am doing is select an image from my gallery, then display it on a ImageView and then upload it to the storage.

Everything works. But my concern is the first time I upload an image, I have tested and takes around a minute to return the download path.

After the first time takes less than a second. My problem is that I want to use that path for another ImageViews after closing the "upload image" activity.

Here is my code.

I have a dialog to select the gallery(I will have the facebook option later)

```
    private View.OnClickListener dialogListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) { clicked.length());
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(EditProfileActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.galleryoptions);
        dialog.setTitle("Gallery Options");

        Button gallery = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonGallery);
        gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
};
```

Then here is the Activity Result

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        //GET PATHS
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        Log.d(TAG, "PICTURE PATH IN PHONE: " + picturePath);
        cursor.close();
        clicked = "iv_"+clicked;
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(clicked, "id", "com.my.project");
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(resID);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        //UPLOAD FILE TO FIREBASE
        Uri file  = Uri. fromFile(new File(picturePath));
        String extension = file.getLastPathSegment();
        extension = extension.substring(extension.lastIndexOf("."));
        StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child("images/"+ user.getUid().toString()+"/"+clicked+extension);
        UploadTask uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file);

        // Register observers to listen for when the download is done or if it fails
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Log.d(TAG, "DOWNLOAD PATH IN FIREBASE: " + downloadUrl);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

The time between both logs "PATH IN PHONE" and "PATH IN FIREBASE" is around a minute the first time, then is quite fast. The question is, do you know a way or method or pattern to have the speed upload all the time and not just the second time?
Or what do you suggest? is it better store the image in Base64 using the realtime database instead of storage?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason you see the lag on your first upload is because Firebase is backed by `Google App Engine` which when your backend is not in use for a long period of time basically puts it in a paused state to save resources.

When you go to make a request when it is in this paused state it needs to spin back up everything which is when you see the lag in upload time

Comment: make sense, do you know a way to manually change the state from paused to resume the backend in firebase for this case? I am new to firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Storage is not backed by App Engine (it shares the same default GCS bucket, but does not run on GAE) but I can understand why that might make you think its slow the first time.

What I think what may be happening is that the underlying connection to the server is getting cached after the first instance and there may be an initial delay due to your location or similar issue.

Can you tell me what general region you are located?
Also, can you verify that if you do any dummy upload (to any location, including a different bucket), then the speed improves?

Comment: Hi Benjamin. I did not try any other region than UK. and every time the first upload last around 1 minute, then the others were almost instantly. What I finally implemented was to include a progressdialog that shows the progress while the upload was in progress.. here it is the implementation https://github.com/casertillo/AndroidProjects/blob/master/TutumpDev/app/src/main/java/com/tutump/tutumpdev/Activities/EditProfileActivity.java#L300 It is the method starting on line 300. Hope it works for you.